# How do I organize a Visual Studio project on GitHub.com?

Tags: github

When uploading my project to GitHub, exactly what files should I upload and how should I organize them?

For example, should I organize them as header files folder, source files folder? Should I provide any visual studio-specific files?

Comment: I only know some files you shouldn't upload. You should have a .gitignore file that should ignore personal info (auth keys, passwords). If you have a dependency manager (composer, npm), it should also ignore folders for dependencies (vendor, node_modules).

Comment: Same layout you're using in the local folder. You might exclude stuff like `.vscode/`; that depends a bit on the others who might use your repo (if they should share the same VSCode settings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating your project with visual studio, put the template of gitignore file [VisualStudio.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) at the root of your project folder